# BigQuery extract repeated JSON

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following data in one column in BigQuery:

{"id": "81", "type": ["{'id2': '12', 'type2': 'main'}", "{'id2': '15', 'type2': 'sub'}"]}

I would like to parse this and have 'id2' and 'type2' as nested fields. I tried using JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(data, "$.type") that correctly creates the nested rows but couldn't process extracting 'id2' and 'type2'. I believe maybe the "s are the issue inside the list, how could I get past those?

UPDATE:

This is the format I would like to achieve.
[image]

Comment: not clear what is expected output! provide example that matches shown input

Comment: fair point Mikhail, I added the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  json_value(json, '$.id') id, array(
    select as struct json_value(trim(type, '"'), '$.id2') as id2, json_value(trim(type, '"'), '$.type2') as type2
    from unnest(json_extract_array(json, '$.type')) type
  ) type
from your_table
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mikhail. Is the new JSON_VALUE_ARRAY() function not usable here because of the "s? I thought that would be a way to avoid the unnesting.

Comment: you can use `JSON_VALUE_ARRAY()` here and in this case you will use `json_value(type, '$.id2') as id2, json_value(type, '$.type2') as type2` so as you can see you still need unnest